# How to Reload/Re-init Bean in Spring boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-bean

I have email config class like this.

```
@Configuration
public class EmailConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private ConfigService configService;


    @Bean
    public JavaMailSender JavaMailSender() {
        JavaMailSenderImpl mailSender = new JavaMailSenderImpl();
        mailSender.setHost(configService.emailHost());
        mailSender.setPort(configService.emailPort());
        mailSender.setUsername(configService.emailAddress());
        mailSender.setPassword(configService.emailPassword());

        return mailSender;
    }
}
```

how to make this bean change the value at runtime every ConfigService was refreshed? I was refresh the ConfigService but the bean's value did not change.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to handle property refresh in Spring boot.
Please check this once - https://www.baeldung.com/spring-reloading-properties.

This will make use of spring in-built capabilities to handle property changes.
And will be extensible for future purposes as well.

Answer (score 0):

To ensure that the JavaMailSender bean is recreated with the updated configuration from the ConfigService, you can annotate the JavaMailSender bean method with @RefreshScope. This annotation tells Spring to recreate the bean whenever its configuration properties change.

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.cloud.context.config.annotation.RefreshScope;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSender;
import org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl;

@Configuration
public class EmailConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private ConfigService configService;

    @Bean
    @RefreshScope
    public JavaMailSender javaMailSender() {
        JavaMailSenderImpl mailSender = new JavaMailSenderImpl();
        mailSender.setHost(configService.emailHost());
        mailSender.setPort(configService.emailPort());
        mailSender.setUsername(configService.emailAddress());
        mailSender.setPassword(configService.emailPassword());
        return mailSender;
    }
}
```

By adding @RefreshScope to the javaMailSender() bean method, Spring will recreate the JavaMailSender bean with the updated configuration whenever the ConfigService is refreshed.